# I have deployed my rasa chatbot to heroku using Docker, can i use that heroku URL in socket.io to get chatbot widget in website?

Tags: python, heroku, nlp, chatbot, rasa

Everything is working as expected when I am running it on my local machine to get chatbot widget.
Here's the code snippet of my local machine index.html

```html
<body>
    <script>!(function () {
        let e = document.createElement("script"),
          t = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        (e.src =
          "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat/lib/index.js"),
          (e.async = !0),
          (e.onload = () => {
            window.WebChat.default(
              {
                customData: { language: "en" },
                socketUrl: "http://localhost:5005",
                // add other props here
              },
              null
            );
          }),
          t.insertBefore(e, t.firstChild);
        })();
    </script>
</body>
```

However, i am not getting same result when i deploy it in on heroku and changed the socketUrl to heruku url.

```html
<body>
    <script>!(function () {
        let e = document.createElement("script"),
          t = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        (e.src =
          "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat/lib/index.js"),
          (e.async = !0),
          (e.onload = () => {
            window.WebChat.default(
              {
                customData: { language: "en" },
                socketUrl: "https://test-rasa-demo.herokuapp.com",
                // add other props here
              },
              null
            );
          }),
          t.insertBefore(e, t.firstChild);
        })();
    </script>
</body>
```

Can someone guide me where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this into your URL `/webhooks/rest/webhook` behind your domain. Ex.: `https://test-rasa-demo.herokuapp.com/webhooks/rest/webhook`

It's a default connectors, for custom connectors from Rasa, check their docs [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/connectors/custom-connectors/)